# Check if MongoDb database is empty via db.collection.count() - doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I connect to MongoDb via Mongoose. Then, when connection is successful, **I want to check whether the database is empty (meaning having no collections)**. If empty, I will seed the database with data.

I am using `db.collection.count()` to count collections but this code doesn't work.

```
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/voddb';
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {  
    console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + dbURI);
    if(mongoose.connection.db.collection.count() == 0) {
        //seed database
    }  
});
```

It throws me an error at `collection.count()`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `mongoose.connection.db.collection` which is a function, You can use `mongoose.connection.db.collection('your_collection_name').count()`

Example :

```js
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/my_db_name';

mongoose.connect(dbURI);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () { 
console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + dbURI);

// To List all Collections of a Database
mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, names) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        names.forEach(function(e,i,a) {
            console.log("----->", e.name);
        });
    }
});

// To Count Documents of a particular collection
mongoose.connection.db.collection('users').count(function(err, count) {
    console.dir(err);
    console.dir(count);

    if( count == 0) {
        console.log("No Found Records.");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Found Records : " + count);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: @chridam : Thanks for your comment, I have updated the snippet.

Comment: Thank, that works. What if I want to check whether a database if empty, without having to check if individual collections?

Comment: @ViolaT Updated the answer.

Comment: you would like to remove this line from the code snippet. `mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection(e.name);`